# git svn fetch - Unable to find .git directory

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have migrated the SVN repository to a local Git repository by using following **git svn clone command**

```
git svn clone <svn-repo>/<project> <git-repo-name>
```

Now I want to synchronize the new local Git repository when the SVN repository changes(new commit). I used following command to fetch any new commits from the original SVN repository:

```
git svn fetch
```

But nothing is fetched after executing above command. It displays as :

```
$ git svn fetch
```

Instaed it shows as :

```
$ git svn fetch
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Unable to find .git directory
at D:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 347.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to change directory into the root of the git repo. The clone operation will have created a sub-folder from within your current folder which contains the new git repository. cd into this folder and then try the svn fetch operation.